# ApiResourceProperty tag can not be compiled to GWT or ignored

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-endpoints, gwt-compiler

We have a GWT app that exposes an API using Google Cloud Endpoints. As we use objectify we can not expose the Key tag to the API. For that we use the ApiResourceProperty in order to make the API ignore the field, but if we do that the GWT compilation fails.

I have tried everything, from using the exclude from source in the gwt.xml to using the @gwtincompatible

So... is there a way to ignore the ApiResourceProperty.class in the GWT compilation?

Any other idea? If not I would have to duplicate my entities for the API

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I had was to create custom DTOs for the API.